# How to compare the two resultsets in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, compare

```
for(int i=0;i<resultset.length;i++)
{
a = select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key ='movie name' and post_id = resultset(i)
}
resultset = (select object_id from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = (select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy = 'actors' and term_id = (Select term_id from wp_terms where name = 'Aamir khan'))


for(int i=0;i<resultset.length;i++)
{
b = select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key ='movie name' and post_id = resultset(i)
}
resultset = (select object_id from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = (select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy = 'actors' and term_id = (Select term_id from wp_terms where name = 'Salman khan'))
```

the value for a & b are the names of the movies done by these actors, i just want to compare these two, and if there is any common movie then it will display that.
If i am not on the write path then please tell me the right path.
This has to be done on wordpress

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, consider taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Note that part: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: you are so far from solution. make your code working first. your pseudo php code is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN on the two results: [here's a quick introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).